# What's the cause of this silent LiveKernelEvent 193?

Tags: windows, bsod, crash, kernel

Brand new system, not OC'ed

- Zotac 4070Ti Trinity
- CPU i5-12600K
- 500GB Kingston SSD
- Transcend 16GB RAM
- Windows 11 Pro 22H2 Build 22621.1265
- Coolermaster MWE 10050 Gold V2
- All drivers and BIOS are up to date

After closing and opening some videos with WMP I found a silent LiveKernelevent 193 in the Reliability Monitor without me noticing any hangs/freezes.

For some reason there's no error log in Event Viewer nor a .dmp file to pinpoint the cause even though I have enabled dump files, disabled Storage Sense and have 396GB of free space.

I only found a .wer file which I uploaded [here](https://www.elevenforum.com/attachments/report-zip.55054/)

[image]

Is there a way to roughly tell from this log containing what the cause might be? Does Parameter 1: 80e give a hint? And should I be worried even if I didn't experience any hangs/freezes?

Comment: This is likely a hardware error. From analyzing your WER file, you should have a dump at `C:\Windows\LiveKernelReports\WATCHDOG\WATCHDOG-20230312-1611.dmp`. If you can find it, please upload it online in zip format. If more such files exist in this folder, you could upload a few more.

Comment: @harrymc Thanks, but that's the issue. The folder is empty, there are no dump files whatsoever.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a hardware/driver error, but except for the WER report,
all other information is missing, even the `.dmp` file indicated
in the WER report.

Try to examine the Event Viewer to see if you can find some
hardware-related error message (or any helpful message).

You have updated all drivers
(*I hope not with a driver-update product!*),
and the computer seems to recover just fine from the error with no
symptoms at all. So if you can find no indication for the problem,
all you can do is keep on using the computer until the error becomes more
seriously detectable (if ever).

As the computer is new, you could ask for it to be replaced,
if you feel that you had the bad luck to buy a problematic computer.

Comment: Can a 193 code be any hardware error not necessarily related to the GPU?

Comment: That's the most likely one if the error code is 0x00000193, which refers to VIDEO_DXGKRNL_LIVEDUMP. I thought about it, but found no support for it in the WER report. But it's still one possibility.

Comment: I managed to find the cause; it occurred again when switching (the modern) Windows Media Player to fullscreen while playing an .mkv video. The video flickered for a second and the hardware error popped up again, again without a dump file.

Comment: What are the video card and its driver?

Comment: A Zotac 4070Ti Trinity with driver version 531.18. What bothers me the most is that there is no .dmp whatsoever. The folder that should contain it is edited on the exact timestamp of the crash but it is empty. So it seems that it the .dmp file is deleted immediately for some reason even though I have enough space.

Comment: This is the latest driver. Windows detects a video driver crash and restarts it immediately. That's what is happening here. I can't say if the missing `.dmp` is because the crash doesn't leave one, or if Windows terminates the driver too fast without giving it enough time. In any case, I suggest contacting Zotac Support, because there's nothing you can do to fix it, except perhaps trying older drivers to see if this is a recent bug. I note on the NVIDIA site the latest driver is [531.29](https://www.nvidia.com/download/driverResults.aspx/200217/en-us/), but better verify with  Zotac Support.

Comment: I contacted nvidia and they were able to reproduce the same issue. They will look into it. Thank you so much for your time!

Answer (score 0):

To solve the LiveKernelEvent 193 error, you must enable this option:
https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/video-playback-settings-in-windows-39ad5cbf-b2d1-2664-bd55-65028db05579#WindowsVersion=Windows_11

["Process video automatically to enhance it"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uH13F.jpg)

Tested the error on different GPUs. The error occurs on all RTX30xx-40xx available to me. There is no error on GTX10xx.
RTX20xx is not available to me.